# jquery json call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to create an array from a json file using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stores = [];
$.getJSON('js/locations.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        stores.push("<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>");  
    }); 
});
</script>
```

But the array appears to be empty when I call it.  The json file looks like this:

```
{
    '1' : 'Store 1',
    '2' : 'Store 2',
    '3' : 'Store 3'
}
```

If anyone could tell me why its not working it would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If you put a break point in a debugger (firebug, chrome, etc) on the value line is the data coming back?

Comment: when do you call the array? seems to me like you might be calling the array before the ajax call has finished??

Comment: I'm calling the array in the body the code above is in the head

Comment: is the location your localhost?? .if thats the case .Chrome browser shows this error ."XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:js/locations.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: Alright I've moved it over to a server.  I'm no longer getting the access control error but my array is still empty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Print, whatserver return. Something like: console.debug(data);
2. Try other json file content. For example this:

   {
     "one": "Singular sensation",
     "two": "Beady little eyes",
     "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
   }

Good luck ;-)

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:js/locations.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: You can't get file from other server. 
If your get page from example.com, you can send ajax requests only to pages example.com/some_some_some_here.json. See "crossdomain ajax restrictions"

Comment: How you load your page? Try in such way: 1. Put your html page and json file on server 2. Open in browser page. For example: http://localhost/mysuperpuperpage.html or http://somehost.com/mysuperpuperpage.html 3. Open firebug / chrome developer toolbar and check, if browser can download content. 4. If all ok, check console.debug . I think, after this steps your code will work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the json isn't valid. Try:

{
    "1": "Store1",
    "2": "Store2",
    "3": "Store3"
}

single quote to double. With the single quotes jsonlint.com don't validate....

Answer (score 0):

IF the location  you are trying to access local json file. webkit browsers dont allow it.
 Try launching chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` . Same access is denied by IE 8+.
`$.getJSON` gives issues in Firefox for reading the local file. Possible solution can be through this.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "a.json",false);
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
req.send(null);
var myJson = req.responseText;
```

Or you can put the JSON as var in your JS file for testing purpose.